# after installing vite for react npm run dev not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite

after successfully installing react js with vite
after using npm i
when i write npm run dev
it show this error
npm run dev

```
> nasheednaldo@0.0.0 dev
> vite

E:\nasheednaldo\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:64
                throw new Error(
                      ^

Error: Cannot find module @rollup/rollup-win32-ia32-msvc. npm has a bug related to optional dependencies (https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4828). Please try `npm i` again after removing both package-lock.json and node_modules directory.
    at requireWithFriendlyError (E:\nasheednaldo\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:64:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nasheednaldo\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:73:48)
    ... 2 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at cjsLoader (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:284:17)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:234:7)
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:217:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:316:24) {
  [cause]: Error: The specified module could not be found.
  \\?\E:\nasheednaldo\node_modules\@rollup\rollup-win32-ia32-msvc\rollup.win32-ia32-msvc.node
      at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1327:18)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
      at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
      at requireWithFriendlyError (E:\nasheednaldo\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:62:10)
      at Object.<anonymous> (E:\nasheednaldo\node_modules\rollup\dist\native.js:73:48)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32) {
    code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
  }
}
```

Node.js v20.9.0

now i tried to reinstall it but it kept happening everytime.

Comment: did you try exactly what the suggestion is telling you

Comment: Try deleting package-lock.json and node-modules
then npm i

Comment: did you remove both `node_modules` and `lockfile` before `npm i`? What's your node and npm version?

Comment: yes i exactly deleted both ``node_modules`` and ``lockfile`` but its  still showing the same error.
my node version is v20.9.0

Comment: Try to go for the latest version of node v20.10.0. I suspect that these issues occur on version conflicts. @FaridaAkhterBanuBalaka

Comment: Try `npm cache clean --force` after removing both `node_modules` and `lockfile`. Then `npm i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in React vite project due to rollup dependency (module not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569907/error-in-react-vite-project-due-to-rollup-dependency-module-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

download this softwere your error will be fix automatically when you install it
"Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x64"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I encountered 2 days ago. Just follow these steps:-

1. Download & install Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/a061be25-c14a-489a-8c7c-bb72adfb3cab/4DFE83C91124CD542F4222FE2C396CABEAC617BB6F59BDCBDF89FD6F0DF0A32F/VC_redist.x64.exe)

2. Restart Your System

3. Delete the old project & create a new one (using vite & npm)
4. Make sure you run `npm install` before `npm run dev`

These steps will work (most probably), this works for me.